# Is it possible to have eclipse as normal application?

Tags: windows, eclipse

I downloaded the eclipse-helios pc version and everytime, if i need to run eclipse i need to click on the eclipse.exe file. Is it possible to run the eclipse application normally as any other application without having to click the eclipse.exe file?

Moreover,when i run the eclipse.exe file, the program always ask me to select the workspace that i am working on. I have selected the use default option to select the workspace permanently, but it seems to pop up everytime i use the eclipse. Is there any way,i could change this?

Comment: What do you mean by **running an application normally**?

Comment: :) `right-click` on eclipse.exe click, `send to > Desktop(create shortcut)`. It will create an "icon" for you. So, that it does not look unusual to start Eclipse to you.

Comment: Why don't you make an shortcut? and what do you mean running it normally?

Comment: Can you explain what so you mean by "run the eclipse application normally"?

Comment: You mean, through a shortcut in the Start menu? Just create a shortcut (right-click on eclipse.exe - create a shortcut) and drag and drop it in the Start menu yourself.

Comment: I did like what you all said but it reads eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library...

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Put eclipse.exe into a directory where you want it to live permanently, and then create a shortcut to it on your Desktop or Start Menu.

However you should also know that there is a real eclipse installer that can do all of this for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a shortcut to the eclipse.exe anywhere on your startmenu or desktop - just use the right mouse button to drag it and select "Create Shortcut" you can then rename it to something better then "eclipse.exe"